# Почему подключение к сайту защищено не полностью?

Tags: wordpress, http, https

В консоли такое предупреждение: c47pj.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://...../' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://......./wp-content/uploads/2019/10/7-2-1024...'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Что это означает я понимаю) Как это исправить? Все ссылки поменяны с помощью плагина Velvet. Что еще нужно сделать?
Установленные плагины на сайте:
Advanced Custom Fields
Contact Form 7
Popup for Contact Form 7
Smart Slider 3
Smush
WP Fastest Cache
Yoast SEO
Velvet Blues Update URLs
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не надо пользоваться сомнительными плагинами типа Velvet. Перенесите сайт правильно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: Наверняка прочитали совет здесь https://www.reg.ru/support/hosting-i-servery/spravka-po-cms/perenos-sayta-na-wordpress-s-odnogo-domena-na-drugoy Гнать надо из профессии за такие советы (я про второй вариант с mysql запросами).

Comment: Менять протокол нужно с пом плагинов типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ работающие с сериализованными данными. Больше ничего не надо. Это если "по месту". А переносить сайт так, как писал  KAGG Design

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы!! Буду знать